# What does $\text{dim}_K L$ mean when $K,L$ are fields? +Example.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

What does $\text{dim}_K L$ when $K,L$ are fields?

From the context in which I have seen it used I believe it means the dimension of the vector space we get from viewing $L$ as a vector space over $K$ and that $\text{dim}_K L=[L:K]$ but I would like some confirmation.

In the example it gives a set $M=\{a+b\sqrt 2~|~a,b \in \Bbb{Q}\}$ and it says $[M:\Bbb{Q}]=2$ would this just be because $\Bbb{Q} \subseteq M$ when we view $M$ as a vector space over $\Bbb{Q}$ we can simply find a basis for $M$ one such basis would be $\{1,\sqrt 2\}$ so then the dimension of $M$ is $2$ so $[M:\Bbb{Q}]=2$?

Finally it says since $\pi$ is transcendental  so $\{1,\pi,\pi^2,\pi^3,...\}$ are linearly independent over $\Bbb{Q}$ so we must have $[\Bbb{R}:\Bbb{Q}]=\infty$ why is this the case could anyone elaborate please?

Comment: Your first paragraph is correct.

Comment: Yep...that's right...except for the third paragraph. The reason that $[\mathbb R: \mathbb Q] = \infty$  is that $1, \pi, \pi^2, \ldots$ are *independent*,...but it's quite possible that they may not span all of $\mathbb R$. (In the second paragraph, I think you mean $L \subset M$ (where $L = \mathbb Q$) rather than the other way around.)

Comment: Suppose they don't span $\Bbb{R}$ then it wouldn't be a basis for $\Bbb{R}$ over $\Bbb{Q}$ so how could we conclude that $[\Bbb{R}:\Bbb{Q}]$ is in fact infinity? And yes I did mean that thanks for pointing it out I will change.

Comment: More precisely, $\dim_{\bf Q}{\bf R}=2^{\aleph_0}$. The reasons for this are purely combinatorial: a vector space of dimension $\kappa$ over an infinite field $F$ has cardinality $\max(\lvert F\rvert,\kappa)$. No need to invoke Lindemann.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of what you said is correct except the last part. You wrote correctly  that $\{1,\pi,\pi^2,\pi^3,...\}$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb Q$ since $\pi$ is trascendental. So $\mathbb R$ *contains* an infinite set of $\mathbb Q$-linearly independent vectors, therefore $\mathrm{dim}_{\mathbb Q}\mathbb R$ is infinite. But it is *not true* that  $\{1,\pi,\pi^2,\pi^3,...\}$ is a base of $\mathbb R$ over $\mathbb Q$. In fact, it is not true that any real number is a finite combination with rational coefficients of those elements. If it were so, $\mathbb R$ would be countable (see comment of tomasz).

Comment: I don't understand your use of the word admits in this context. Also I don't understand how you can conclude "therefore dim is infinite" part?

Comment: @CliveB: "Foo admits a Bar" usually means "There is a Bar for Foo".

Comment: If a vector space $V$ has finite dimension $n$, then you cannot find $n+1$ linearly independent vectors. Therefore, if $V$ contains an infinite set of l.i. vectors, it cannot have finite dimension.

Comment: @guestDiego that last comment of yours just made the penny drop for me. Got it now many thanks. I just have one last comment to add to your last line "In fact, it is not true that any real number is finite and rational combination of those elements." surely this is true only for real numbers not in the set as you could write $\pi=1\cdot \pi$ for example?

Comment: What I meant (the sentence was perhaps a bit confused, I have re-edited it) is that you cannot write any real number $a\in \mathbb R$ as $ a=q_0+q_1\pi+\ldots+q_n \pi^n$ with $q_i\in\mathbb Q$. For example, $\sqrt{2}$ cannot (probably!) be written in tha way.